# Bundle product showing "backordered" when associated products are in stock

Tags: magento

All of my bundle products are showing "backordered" and I don't know why.

I've checked a few and `Manage Stock` is set to `No` and the products that make up the bundle are in stock.

What would cause this unexpected availability status on my bundle products?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because by default bundle product qty is 0 that is why it showing all bundle products on backorder.